# how sum of 2 arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

i got below mentioned error when run code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkPositionIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at Collection.Dynamycmaasiv.Collecktionaddlist.main(Collecktionaddlist.java:36)
```

code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> num = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> numodd = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> numeven = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> sumoffevenandodd = new LinkedList<Integer>();// help
                                                                        // me
                                                                        // to
                                                                        // solve

    for (double i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        num.add((int) i);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            numeven.add((int) i);
        } else {
            numodd.add((int) i);

        }
    }

    System.out.println(num);
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    System.out.println(numodd);
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    System.out.println(numeven);

    for (int i =0; i<numeven.size(); i++){

        sumoffevenandodd.addAll(numeven.get(i)+ numodd.get(i), null);
    }

    System.out.println(sumoffevenandodd);
}
```

}

Comment: `sumoffevenandodd.addAll(numeven.get(i)+ numodd.get(i), null);` this is where the exception occurs. `addAll` takes a `Collection` as parameter, not an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the intention of the question is

num odd

[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]

num even

[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48]

sum of odd and even

[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69, 73, 77, 81, 85, 89, 93, 97]

then

for (int i =0; i< numeven.size(); i++){

```
        sumoffevenandodd.add(numeven.get(i)+ numodd.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**addAll()** is not about **adding up numbers**. It is about **adding all** the elements of the method parameter to the collection itself.

So, you need to loop, like

```
int sum = 0;
for (Integer numberFromList : numeven) {
  sum = sum + numberFromList;
```

Or, if you have Java8, you can use streams:

```
int sumEven = numeven.stream().sum();
```

Sum, done.

And for the record: the real lesson to be learned here: read the **javadoc**. Don't assume that method called *addAll()* does what you **suppose** it does. Turn to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) and inform yourself what reality thinks about your assumptions.

But just to be clear; as I got carried away with your question, too.

In your code, if you change

```
sumoffevenandodd.addAll(numeven.get(i)+ numodd.get(i), null);
```

to

```
sumoffevenandodd.add(numeven.get(i)+ numodd.get(i));
```

it should work, too.

Long story short: if you intended to really have a list with 50 sums within, then my first paragraphs do not really help with your problem. 
But it isn't exactly clear what you wanted to do; so I leave my answer as is - to address both possible explanations what is "wrong" in your logic.

Comment: One can also say "read the question". I am not so sure any more if I am really correct with my assumptions either.

Comment: Dear GhostCat, how find difference , put minus but get no result: sumoffevenandodd.add(Collections.singletonList(numeven.get(i) - numodd.get(i)));

Comment: Sorry, that part was wrong: when you really want the sum or delta, you don't need that Collections call. Just use `add(numeven.get(i) OP numodd.get(i))`   where OP is +, -, *, whatever. And side note: names like evenNumbers, or oddNumbers are much better to read!